# Python HTTP Server: Serving a 30 KB png only partially transfers

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, httpserver

I've got a very crude python3 HTTP server (using BaseHTTPRequestHandler and HTTPServer from the http.server module). Upon receiving a get request for a ".graph" resource, matplotlib creates a png and transfers it back in the response.

When this file is being served via localhost it works fine. However, when it is being served over the network it only partially transfers. The file in question is about 34KB and only 13KB is received. I've checked this in chrome and firefox. I'm a bit stumped as to the cause of this behaviour - it doesn't look like the timeout is being hit either.

I was hoping someone familiar with this module might be able to point me in the right direction?

Server setup:

```
def http_server_thread():
    global HTTP_SERVER_RUNNING
    HttpHandler = Handler
    HttpHandler.protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1"
    HttpHandler.timeout = 60
    HttpServer = HTTPServer((config.SERVER_HOST, config.SERVER_PORT), HttpHandler)
    while(HTTP_SERVER_RUNNING is True):
        HttpServer.handle_request()
```

GET handling code:

```
def do_GET(self):
    if (self.path == "/"):  
        self.send_root_html()
    elif self.path.endswith(".graph"):
        dev,res = self.path_to_device_resource()
        png = graph_data.open_png_graph_device_resource(dev,res)
        self.send_response(OK, "OK")
        self.send_header("Content-type","image/png")
        self.send_header("Content-length", str(len(png)))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(png)
```

EDIT:

[PNG which is generated, and saved OK from matplotlib](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2866686/http_server_png_issue/should_see.png)

[PNG which loads in brower](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2866686/http_server_png_issue/what_loads.png)

[Wireshark PCAP of transation](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2866686/http_server_png_issue/capture_failed.pcapng)

Comment: What is `len(png)` returning? What does the header returned by the server to the client say the `Content-Length` is? Might be best to post the full header received by the client.

Comment: See what happens if you add `self.wfile.flush()` after the `write()`. Alternatively, try taking out the "HTTP/1.1" line.

Comment: @C.B. len(png) matches what is being placed in Content-Length. The PNG is created with matplotlib with a request, currently it is 31,432 bytes. The response start line and headers can be seen in packets 9 and 10 of the first pcap.

Comment: @WilliamMcBrine unfortunately flushing did not work, and I am specifically using HTTP 1.1 for persistent connections.